# Why does the Adobe Creative Cloud application think that Edge Reflow CC is not installed even though it is?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-creative-cloud

I am using a Windows 7 PC along with an Adobe Creative Cloud subscription. On the Apps tab, the Edge Reflow CC (Preview) app keeps showing up under the "Find New Apps" list even though the app is installed. Attempting to install the app reinstalls the app and puts it under the "Your Apps" list, but restarting Creative Cloud Desktop makes it appear again in the "Find New Apps" list. I know that the offending software is prerelease, but this seems more like a bug with Creative Cloud itself rather than with the offending app (and the other prerelease app, Edge Code CC (Preview), shows up properly in the "Your Apps" list when it is installed). How can I convince it that Edge Reflow is in fact installed?

Comment: Perhaps contacting Adobe and/or filing a bug report would help. The CC management program is rather buggy.

Comment: @Bob Adobe doesn't seem to respond to my bug reports. I've reported several bugs but never got any responses/fixes.

Comment: Adobe does not seem to respond to bug reports that I submit either, but I've found that by posting on the Creative Cloud forum, you can sometimes get a great enough following from other users having the same problem that Adobe eventually notices and resolves the issue. I did this, asked Customer Support, and they insisted it was a problem on my end. I made this horrible Customer Support experience public in the post related to the topic, and it resulted in Adobe taking action. [Here](http://tinyurl.com/ofvqsu4) is what I did.